# Armazenar retorno de dados do Ajax global

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Atualmente estou utilizando *ajax* fazendo várias requisições diferentes para consultas.

Ex:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "getData.php",
  data: { nome:nome, endereco: endereco }
})
  .done(function( data ) {
var dados = data;
    //aqui faço todas validações que preciso
  });
```

Porém, quando preciso fazer uma nova validação de forma diferente, fora do retorno .done eu não tenho acesso a 'dados' de `data`.

Pensei se poderia de alguma forma fazer essa requisição *ajax* e armazenar os dados para não precisar a cada necessidade de validação fazer uma nova requisição.

Comment: O bloco `.done()` é executado **após** a requisição quando não ocorre erro. Se o objetivo for validar algo **antes** da requisição, implemente um bloco `beforeSend`. Detalhes na documentação do ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: certo, veja o que preciso seria algo como armazenar o que vem do retorno do `ajax` em uma váriável e acessar ela fora fora do escopo `.done()`.
Ex: no ajax acima tenho a váriável dados, após fechar a tag do done eu não consigo mais acessar essa váriavél.

Se eu tiver eu precisar mais embaixo validar um novo campo exemplo comparar `if($("#enderecob") == dados.endereco) { // tratar aqui }` , isso fora do done, não funciona, tem alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Tem como se esse if estiver dentro de uma função.

Comment: Entendi, é que eu ainda não vi nenhum exemplo assim, e no meu caso hoje a cada vez que preciso de uma informação do PHP no JS estou fazendo uma nova requisição ajax para obter os dados para tratar a informação.
Procurei alguma informação nesse sentido e encontrei algo que o ajax e assicronomo e não permite trabalhar de forma global somente no dentro do escopo.